# Android SDK hang device on launch

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-2.2-froyo

Hi i am beginner and i want to write simple on click event so i come up with these code in Android SDK and Eclipse :

```
package com.example.aplic;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                tx.setText("yourtext");
            }
         });

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

and :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.aplic.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/abc_action_mode_done"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is when i launch the code on emulator it hang and reset and when i launch it in the real device , it close the program, I dont know what is wrong with it , do i use wrong event ?

PS: When i delete the onclick event part, it works fine but it don't react on the click.

activity_main.xml :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.deomanapp.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Comment: what is the name of this xml file?

Comment: The name is fragment_main.xml .

Comment: then follow @Raghunandan's answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the button belongs to `fragment_main.xml`.

From your comment

> The name is fragment_main.xml

Its not hanging. Its a crash. You are probably getting `NullPointerException`.

Change to

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        Button b = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView tx = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tx.setText("yourtext");
        }
     });
        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: could you explain more, it give me new errors.it told me to delete first override , so the program run without crash but shows me a blank page.

Comment: @user38322 there will no errors. What explanation do you want

Comment: the error is:
The method onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method MainActivity.java

Comment: @user38322 post `activity_main.xml` do oyu have a framelayout there??

Comment: @Shombol-shagol nothing wrong at all. just clean and build your project it should work.